# What would be a good hadoop folder structure which can handle these scenarios?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Folder structure inside HDFS should support yearly, monthly and daily processing of data. If we have to do the processing for last 16 days/ 21 days, the framework should support that. Any adhoc number of days, the processing should be done without human intervention except for the number of days specification and starting date. HDFS path specification should be automated. Default will be daily processing of files.

The framework should be integrated with the Map Reduce code as it has to know which folders it needs to look into to start the job.

Current:
Eg:

/user/projectname/sourcefiles/datasetname/yyyy/mm/dd/timestamp/filename

But this doesn't satisfy all requirements. For example, if we have to process data for past 16 days.

"/user/projectname/sourcefiles/datasetname/yyyy/mm/[01][0-9]/timestamp/filename" This path will not work as 19th day file will also be included.

And how do you ensure that timestamp of HDFS folder structure and Map Reduce job are in sync ?

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. use path globbing - calculate the path string for the days you wish to process - see here [http://books.google.co.il/books?id=Nff49D7vnJcC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=path+globbing+pattern+hadoop&source=bl&ots=IihwWu8xXr&sig=g7DLXSqiJ7HRjQ8ZpxcAWJW0WV0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Fp13Uey9AaS50QXJq4B4&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=path%20globbing%20pattern%20hadoop&f=false](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=Nff49D7vnJcC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=path%20globbing%20pattern%20hadoop&source=bl&ots=IihwWu8xXr&sig=g7DLXSqiJ7HRjQ8ZpxcAWJW0WV0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Fp13Uey9AaS50QXJq4B4&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=path%20globbing%20pattern%20hadoop&f=false)
2. use symbolic links to help you have more than one hierarchy - only available in Java API though - see here http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/08/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-apache-hadoop-0-21/

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a folder to MAP Reduce , it will process all the files in that folder. You can create weekly folders or fortnightly folders. I hope that would help